# Visual Studio 2010 Error: SSAS: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: visual-studio-2010, error-handling

I installed visual studio 2010 but when I want to create new project this error occured:

class not registered(exception from hresult:0x80040154(regdb_e_classnotreg))

what I must do?

Comment: do you have Threatfire antivirus? this software may cause this kind of problem in vs2010

Comment: no I disable my antivirus but it dosent work:(

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the OWC component installation became corrupted.

Try to repair your "Microsoft Office 2003 Web Components" installation.

You can download it from Microsoft here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7287252c-402e-4f72-97a5-e0fd290d4b76&DisplayLang=en

If that doesn't work,

You can try repairing MDAC by downloading this app here: http://www.macropool.com/en/download/repair_mdac.html